# Render a BMP, JPEG, or PNG Image with DirectX?

Tags: winapi, 3d, directx, textures, direct3d

How do you render a BMP, JPEG, or PNG image file in 3D with DirectX in Windows? (E.g. let's say I want to render four images so that they look like a cubicle or something.)

I've seen this done easily with a Java OpenGL library (JME I think?), but it seems like DirectX needs textures, and doesn't take in regular images. :(

Is this correct? If so, how do I convert it to a texture programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DirectX 9: [D3DXCreateTextureFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172801%28VS.85%29.aspx)

DirectX 10: [D3DX10CreateTextureFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172671%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172667%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

DirectX 11: [D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Read the details of each, but most all of the popular file formats are supported. (includes BMP, JPG, and PNG)

Go here: http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9781598220537/

Download the "source code part II" from the "samples and resources" section.  Look at the chapter 7 source code samples.  Optionally, you could buy the book.

Comment: unfortunately, link is now broken

Comment: @Kracken - Unfortunately, the book I was referencing may be out of support by the publisher. However, just go to Amazon and look for books by Frank Luna including any of his "Introduction to 3D Game Programming" series. I'm fairly certain that was what I was referencing.